# How do you change an IBAction UIButton's image in Swift?

Tags: image, swift, if-statement, uibutton, xcode6

```
    if(SelectedRestaurant == "Yo!Sushi, UK"){
        BowlOnePrice = YoUkGreenPrice
        Currency = Pounds

    }

@IBAction func BowlOne(sender: UIButton) {}
```

So I've got an if statement and a UIbutton linked as an IBAction. In the storyboard the button is an image. I want to be able to change the image in the if statement. But I can't access the "BowlOne" button. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `IBOutlet` instead of a `@IBAction`

An `@IBAction` is called whenever the button is pressed
An `@IBOutlet` is used to set and retrieve data from the button this includes the background image, title and well.. whatever you could think of

After adding the `@IBOutlet` you can use

```
@IBOutlet weak var BowlOneButton: UIButton!
BowlOneButton.setImage(“yourUIImage”, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

In your if statement you could use:

```
@IBOutlet weak var BowlOneButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func BowlOne(sender: UIButton) {}

if(SelectedRestaurant == "Yo!Sushi, UK"){
    BowlOnePrice = YoUkGreenPrice
    Currency = Pounds
    BowlOneButton.setImage(“Yo!Shushi Image”, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried that a while ago and it caused the simulator to crash, but now that I try it again, it works!